# Android : Permission doesn't seems to work and icon doesn't want to display

Tags: android, icons, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have an app that supposed to work on android TV, so befor posting it on App Store I wanted to test it on my own Android TV.

But when I install it I have 3 problemes :

1) I don't know why but my permissions doesn't seems to work

2) My app isn't dipslayed on the menu, you can only find it on settings-->app

3) The icon is the android default icon and not my own icon

Here's my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.package">

<!-- read sd card -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- write sd card -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- internet state -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- to disable recent app button -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<!-- AccountManager -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<!-- same -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- don't rember -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:banner="@drawable/my_logo_temp"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_logo_temp"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/my_logo_temp"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".account.AuthenticatorService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":auth" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/auth" />
    </service>
</application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: Case 3: Remove banner and icon from Mainactivity It should be always on Application tag so put it in the application tag this will resolve your problem.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Thanks it worked just fine for the logo ! Do you have an idea for my others problems ?

Comment: @Kolopx see my answer. let me kow whether it works or not. Don't forgot to accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer hope this Help you.

Case 3 : Remove banner and icon from Mainactivity It should be always on Application tag so put it in the application tag.

Case 2 : Remove Existing Theme and Apply **android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"** on application tag.

I always Prefer to write this much of code when start developing TV application.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor"
    android:required="false" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <-- Your Permission -->
    <-- You Application Tag -->
```

Don't Forget to add compile **'com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.2.1'** dependency in your build.gradle file. I was used this dependency when created the app you can change the version according to your project.

Try this one may be this help you.

For Case 1 : Permission issue it will be resolved if do all the above steps.

Comment: The case (3) was solver but I still have the same problem for the case (1) nad (2). Also my app need the coordinate of the TV, isn't it a problem that I use : **<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />** ?

Comment: In android TV there isn't any GPS provider so if you are fetching location or something like that it won't work.

Comment: For GPS I don't know but the real problem is that my permission still doesn't seems to work... The only problem left in my manifest is **"App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter. See issue explanation for more details."** and **"Attribute banner is only used in API level 21 and higher (current min is 17)"**

Comment: @Kolopox which version of api you are currently using?

Comment: If you are using API level below 21 your app will not work in TV.Android TV apps development start from API level 21.See the [doc here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/index.html).

Comment: I changed my app min to 21 and max to 25, my TV is 5.1.1 (22) so it should work but it doesn't... Any other ideas ?

Comment: @Kolopox Try to remove max. I never used max version in my application then try.Can please show me your build.gradle file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146125/discussion-between-andy-developer-and-kolopox).

Answer (score 0):

Put your "logo" icon in the `mipmap` folder and change the following:

```
android:banner="@mipmap/my_logo_temp"
android:icon="@mipmap/my_logo_temp"
android:logo="@mipmap/my_logo_temp"
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not the Problem.

Comment: I had similar issue and this way solved my problem, maybe it can help now as well.